# req.body is empy {} when using http. post in angular and node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose, angular10

**This is my service.ts file**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Items } from "./inventory.model";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";


import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
const BACKEND_URL = environment.APIUrl + "/Items/";

@Injectable({
providedIn: "root",
})
export class InventoryService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

addItem(
itemNo: string,
itemName: string,
maker: string,
unitPrize: string,
sellingPrize: string,
Qty: string
) {



const ItemData = new FormData();
ItemData.append("itemNo", itemNo);
ItemData.append("item_name", itemName);
ItemData.append("maker", maker);
ItemData.append("unitPrize", unitPrize);
ItemData.append("sellingPrize", sellingPrize);
ItemData.append("Qty", Qty);


  this.http
  .post<{ message: string; items: Items }>(
    BACKEND_URL,
    ItemData
  )
  .subscribe((responseData) => {

     console.log(responseData);


  });

  }
  }
```

**This is my item.js in back-end routes**

```
const express = require("express");
const ItemController = require("../controllers/item");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = express.Router();

router.post("", ItemController.savepost);
```

**This is my Item.js file in Controller**

```
    const ItemModel = require('../models/item');

exports.savepost = (req, res, next) => {

  if(Object.keys(req.body).length === 0)
  {
    console.log(req.body);
  }


  const items = new ItemModel({

    item_no: req.body.itemNo,
    item_name: req.body.itemName,
    maker: req.body.maker,
    unitPrize: req.body.unitPrize,
    sellingPrice: req.body.sellingPrize,
    Qty: req.body.Qty,


  });


  console.log(items.item_no);


  items.save().then(addItem => {
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "Item added Successfully",
          items: {
            ...addItem,
            id: addItem._id
          }
        });
  }).catch(error => {

  res.status(500).json({

    message: error
  })
}
);

}
```

**THis is my Item model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  item_no: { type: String, required: true },
  item_name: { type: String, required: true },
  maker: { type: String, required: true },
  unitPrize: { type: Number, required: true },
  sellingPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
  Qty: { type: Number, required: true },



});
```

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Items',itemSchema);

**Response error shows message like this**

*Items validation failed", message: "Items validation failed: item_no: Path `item_no` is required., item_name: Path `item_name` is required., maker: Path `maker` is required., unitPrize: Path `unitPrize` is required., sellingPrice: Path `sellingPrice` is required., Qty: Path `Qty` is required.",*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `/` in your route

```
router.post("/", ItemController.savepost);
```

use this code in app.js because you don't parse req.body

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

please try following code

```
const ItemData =  {
  itemNo,
  item_name,
  maker,
  unitPrize,
  sellingPrize,
  Qty
}
const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}  
const body=JSON.stringify(ItemData);
this.http.post<{ message: string; items: Items }>(BACKEND_URL, body,{'headers':headers}).subscribe((responseData) => {
  console.log(responseData);
});
```

I tested backend code, and it's right, the problem is about post request in frontend code, you can check the post request [docomentation](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-http-post-example/)

Comment: this already in my app.js and still not working

Comment: in `savepost` log the `req.body` and show me the result

Comment: Req body output {}

Comment: do you put item data in body of request? and What does service.ts file do ?

Comment: yes.you can see im ading data to "Itemadata" in service.tc and pass that itemData via HTTP POST

Comment: in invntory.ts file im calling the addItem function and passing form data

Answer (score 0):

> you send your Object data without parsing in JSON format. so before sending the request first convert it to a pure JSON. you can achieve this after adding this code in the app.js file.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: this already in my app.js and still not working